# Django Want to print the date & time for today

Tags: python, django, datetime, date, view

I want to print some sort of time stamp or  some sort of function to tell what day and time it is in a template. In my views I have

```
time = datetime.now()
```

and in my template I have

```
{{time}}
```

All this does is prints out a `<type 'datetime.date'>` object.

Comment: Did you use `from datetime import datetime` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, this should work:

```
from datetime import datetime

def a_view(request):
    return render_to_response("a_template.html", {
        'time':datetime.now(),
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then render the datetime object in your template:

```
<p>{{time}}</p>
```

Use the built-in date filter as described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) to format your date if you like.

Comment: There is a template builtin that does this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#now

Comment: don't use `datetime.now()` use `django.utils.timezone.now()` and set `USE_TZ=True` instead then `{{time}}` should display the time using the current timezone.

Answer (score 84):

if its just in the template, use [now](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#now)

```
It is {% now "f" %}
```

Comment: Came here to say this. There is a built-in template filter that does exactly what OP is asking to do. Not sure why this is the accepted answer. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#now